# Family permit as extended family member of EEA/EU national

Tags: eu, family

I am Pakistani, and I have an Italian work permit for unlimited period. My uncle with whom I live in Italy has Italian citizenship. My questions are:

1. My uncle (brother of my mother) is an Italian national; can I apply for an EEA family permit as the extended family member of Italian citizen?
2. What proof should I present to relate myself to my uncle?  I have some documents such as my birth certificate and the birth certificates of my uncle and my mother.
3. I have a certificate from the municipality (*comune*) that shows that my uncle and I have lived in the same house in Italy for more than 3 years
4. My uncle is self employed, so he has sufficient funds to support me during the visit to the UK. We can document this with bank statements, etc.

Are there any other documents required?

Comment: I'm a bit confused - if you have an Italian work permit, why do you need an EEA family one? And why do you have 4 paragraphs talking about Italy, then suddenly one about the UK?

Comment: Sorry. My mistake .my actual question was about eea family permit because I want to travel uk with my uncle .all details are above

Comment: Possible duplicate of [eea family permit as extended family members of eea/eu national](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7175/eea-family-permit-as-extended-family-members-of-eea-eu-national)

Comment: Does your Italian residence permit indicate that you are a family member of an EU/EEA citizen?

Comment: No .but i came italy as independent. Then live with my uncle in same house and we have certificate of local council which indicate that I am member of his household.

Comment: Plzzzzzzzzz reply

Comment: @PervaiZKhan The site is not very active and everybody here is a volunteer so people answer when they can, there is no need to post the same thing several times or repeatedly ask people to answer.

Comment: @Gagravarr the EEA family permit is a UK visa that allows the family member of an EEA national to travel to the UK under the EU freedom of movement rules (in the company of the EEA national, therefore).  It is free of charge and granted with far less scrutiny than a standard visitor visa.  It is therefore a natural choice for the OP, but as he is not the spouse or descendant or dependent ascendant of the EEA national, he needs to show that he qualifies as an "extended family member."  This explains the information regarding the circumstances in Italy.

Comment: Hello PervaiZKhan, did you apply for the EEA family permit?  How did it work out for you?

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, you can apply for an EEA family permit.
2. To prove your relationship to your uncle, you can use your birth certificate and those of your mother and uncle (what other proof could there possibly be?).
3. The certificate showing that you are a member of your uncle's household should establish that you qualify as an extended family member.  The criterion is (emphasis added) "you must be able to show that you’re dependent on the EEA citizen **or are a member of their household,** or have a serious health condition and rely on them to care for you."
4. Okay, but to qualify for the EEA family permit, you need only to establish that you qualify as an extended family member. There is no test of financial means.

Yes, there are other documents required.  For example, you have to document the fact that your uncle is an EEA citizen.  His passport or identity card will do that.

Have a look at the guidance published by the UK authorities, and let us know what specific questions you have about the guidance: https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/documents-you-must-provide